# Reading csv files in chunks with `readr::read_csv_chunked()`

Tags: r, csv, chunks, readr

I want to read larger csv files but run into memory problems. Thus, I would like to try reading them in chunks with `read_csv_chunked()` from the `readr` package. My problem is that I do not really understand the `callback` argument.

This is a minimal example of what I have tried so far (I know I would have to include the desired operations into `f()`, otherwise there would not be an advandate in terms of memory usage, right?):

```
library(tidyverse)
data(diamonds)
write_csv(diamonds, "diamonds.csv") # to have a csv to read

f <- function(x) {x}
diamonds_chunked <- read_csv_chunked("diamonds.csv", 
                                     callback = DataFrameCallback$new(f),
                                     chunk_size = 10000)
```

I tried to keep the `callback` argument close to the example from the official documentation:

```
# Cars with 3 gears
f <- function(x, pos) subset(x, gear == 3)
read_csv_chunked(readr_example("mtcars.csv"), 
                 DataFrameCallback$new(f), 
                 chunk_size = 5)
```

However, I receive the error below which seems to appear after the first chunk has been read since I see the progress bar moving to 18%.

> Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : unused argument (index)

I already tried to include the manipulations that I want to make inside of `f()`, but I still got the same error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out that the function to be called in `DataFrameCallback$new()` always needs to have one additional argument (`pos` in the example from the documentation). This argument does not have to be used so I do not really understand its purpose. But at least, it works this way.

Does anyone know more details about this second argument?

Answer (score 6):

`pos` means **position**, it's the index number of the first line in every chunk. Using this callback function, you can process every line in the chunk.

Below is the official example from
https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/callback.html

> **ChunkCallback** Callback interface definition, all callback
>   functions should inherit from this class.
>
> **SideEffectChunkCallback** Callback function that is used only for side
>   effects, no results are returned.
>
> **DataFrameCallback** Callback function that combines each result together
>   at the end.
>
> **AccumulateCallBack** Callback function that accumulates a single result.
>   Requires the parameter acc to specify the initial value of the
>   accumulator. The parameter acc is NULL by default.

```
# Print starting line of each chunk
f <- function(x, pos) print(pos)
read_lines_chunked(readr_example("mtcars.csv"), SideEffectChunkCallback$new(f), chunk_size = 5)

# The ListCallback can be used for more flexible output
f <- function(x, pos) x$mpg[x$hp > 100]
read_csv_chunked(readr_example("mtcars.csv"), ListCallback$new(f), chunk_size = 5)
```

Comment: Rather than linking to external URL, please add relevant code and explanation in the answer.